# Centre percentage grid, HTML

Tags: html, css, percentage

I'm currently building my own little fluid grid for my own personal use before I move onto Sass and Less as I have no need for the large frameworks as I wish to understand some of the more simple steps behind them. What I'm trying to do is centre the columns based on the page. As the wrapper only uses 90% width of the screen

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="Column">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Column">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Column last">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}

.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width : 90%;
}

.Column{
    float : left;
    width : 22%;
    margin-right : 4%;
}

.last{
    margin-right : 0;
}
```

I've setup a little test here where I hope to centre the columns http://jsfiddle.net/rjtK9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper is already centered. Your columns are floating left inside the wrapper. Therefore, you should probably just increase the size of your columns:

```
.Column{
    float : left;
    width : 30%;
    margin-right : 4%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's already centered, you've just been two conservative in giving the width
 
I just put up a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anirudhvarma/8zNCb/)

What I did was give 33% width to Column and a 20px gutter to the right.
the add the following css

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

The above code includes the padding in the 33% width. 

For more info on box-sizing check [check here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: A interesting solution, I'm going to +1 this aswell but won't be the solution i pick, thank you.

Comment: No probs, glad I could help. But It would help if you read the article by Chris Coyier, it helped me alot when i started with responsive CSS layouts